# iOS DropBox API authentication issue

Tags: objective-c, dropbox-api

I'm trying to implement the dropbox sync api.

When I run this code:

```
- (void)getDropBoxAuthenticationPageWithViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
    [[DBAccountManager sharedManager] linkFromController:viewController];
}
```

I get a viewcontroller popping up saying: "This app can't be used with the sync API"

But if I download the dropbox app and then run this code, it passes me to the dropbox app and the authentication is perfect.

What am I doing wrong???

Some more details:

The status of my dropbox app is Development,

The permission type is "Full Dropbox"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only use "File type" or "App folder" permissions with the Sync API. Your app has "Full Dropbox" permissions and is thus not compatible with the Sync API.